# How to get refresh_token expiration date at client side?

Tags: oauth, identity

Hi I am using OAuth Identity service to manage the security mechanism of my application. I am able to generate access and refresh token.My response looks like following:

```
"access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.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.25AuQ54-i_i97BJUHgNdNYStADAz02Y89lZDHk3hiNA",`"token_type": "bearer",`"expires_in": 3599,"refresh_token": "414e30e7-95bb-4a89-b92c-3d3d73c7e605",`"as:client_id": "1",".issued": "Wed, 06 Jan 2016 22:55:37 GMT"`".expires": "Wed, 06 Jan 2016 23:55:37 GMT"`
```

I am able to get Access token expiration time , but I am not getting refresh token expiration time. I want to use the refresh token expiration time at client end. Please ley me know how can I do so. I tried to add claim"refreshtokenexpires_in" in the identity ticket, but I don't see it in final response.I add it in CreateAsync method in pplicationRefreshTokenProvider. My method is given below:

```
public override async Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
    {
        var clientid = context.Ticket.Properties.Dictionary["as:client_id"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientid))
        {
            return;
        }
        var existingRefreshTokenId = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:existingRefreshTokenId");
        if (existingRefreshTokenId == null)
        {
            var refreshTokenId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var refreshTokenProperties = new AuthenticationProperties(context.Ticket.Properties.Dictionary)
            {
                IssuedUtc = context.Ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(10)

            };
            var refreshTokenTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(context.Ticket.Identity, refreshTokenProperties);
            _refreshTokens.TryAdd(refreshTokenId, refreshTokenTicket);
            context.SetToken(refreshTokenId);
            var refreshtokeninfo = new RefreshTokenInfo()
            {
                Secret = "secret",
                ClientId = clientid,
                RefreshToken = refreshTokenId,
                RefreshTokenLifeTime = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RefreshTokenLifeTime"]),
                IssuedUtc = refreshTokenProperties.IssuedUtc,
                ExpiresUtc = refreshTokenProperties.ExpiresUtc,
                UserName = refreshTokenTicket.Identity.GetUserName(),
                ProtectedTicket = context.SerializeTicket()
            };
            var result = await ApplicationUserManager.AddRefreshToken(refreshtokeninfo);
            if (result)
            {
                context.Ticket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("refreshtokenexpires_in", Convert.ToString(refreshTokenProperties.ExpiresUtc)));
                context.SetToken(refreshTokenId);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any solution where I can use OAuth classes/properties to store and  pass on the refresh token time span to client. So I found an alternative, I stored the refreshTokenExpirationDuration in the table and then I concatenated it to my refreshtokenId and passed it to client.Something like as shown below:

```
//Get the refresh token duration from the Table
        var refreshTokenExpirationDuration = TimeSpan.FromHours(tenant.RefreshTokenTimeSpan);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ClientId))
        {
            var existingRefreshTokenId = context.OwinContext.Get<string>(_existingRefreshTokenId);
            if (existingRefreshTokenId == null)
            {
                //Create new refreshtokenId if doesn't exist
                var refreshTokenId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                //Add properties to the refresh token
                var refreshTokenProperties = new AuthenticationProperties(context.Ticket.Properties.Dictionary)
                {
                    IssuedUtc = context.Ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc,
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(tenant.RefreshTokenTimeSpan)

                };
                var refreshTokenTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(context.Ticket.Identity,refreshTokenProperties);
                //Concatenate the refresh token duration from table to the refresh token id.
                context.SetToken(String.Format("{0};{1}", refreshTokenId,refreshTokenExpirationDuration.TotalSeconds));
            }
        }
```

Just shared in case it's useful to anybody.